# Cordova Angular2 Typescript

Tags: cordova, typescript, angular

I develop an web application un Angular2 and i want to use the same in Cordova.

I arrive to compile all file un single file un JS, but never launch the application.

Anyone know a good solution for this ? I view two template for this, but it's out of date.

I follow all tutorial on : https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

When i launch my application in nodejs, that's work.

I try to output in single file .js. But doesn't work.

My setup :
In root script folder (not in www)

```
app
--app.component.ts
--main.ts
node_modules ...
typings ...
index.html
package.json
styles.css
systemjs.config.js
tsconfig.json
typings.json

tsconfig.json : pastebin.com/S53zfUdS
typings.json : pastebin.com/6Uv1pxqU
systemjs.config.js : pastebin.com/NSXWYmLF
```

1) I try to load file on code.angular.com => not result, application doesn't work
2) Typescript output strange JS. (pastebin.com/sn73MXAy)

Thank's for all

Comment: any reason why you are not using ionic2 for this? I'm sure they provide up to date project starters.

Comment: Thank's for you response, but i want to use without ionic project.

Comment: what are you using as a module loader?

Comment: I try with systemjs. But, i compile typescript with node, it's possible the problems ?

Comment: sharing your setup, what you have tried so far would help a lot. :) Or at least any error you are getting.

Comment: I update mys post, and update all to github
https://github.com/Hantse/cordova-angular2